# Download GeoJSON file using SQL API call with PHP

Tags: php, sql, cartodb

I'm trying to download a GeoJSON file using the Carto SQL API and PHP. I can download the file successfully by entering the single line SQL query in the browser or using JavaScript's window.open(), but I cant seem to figure out how to do it using PHP.

The format of the SQL API call is:

```
https://{username}.carto.com/api/v2/sql?format=GeoJSON&q=SELECT * FROM {table_name}
```

My attempt:

```
<?php

  $query = 'https://{username}.carto.com/api/v2/sql?format=GeoJSON&filename=ligonier_south_goshen1.geojson&q=SELECT * FROM {username}.ligonier_south_goshen1';
    
  file_get_contents($query);

?>
```

I've also tried:

```
<?php

  $query = 'https://{username}.carto.com/api/v2/sql?format=GeoJSON&q=SELECT * FROM {username}.ligonier_south_goshen1';
  $fileName = 'ligonier_south_goshen1.geojson';
  $result = file_get_contents($query);
  file_put_contents($fileName, $result);

  if(file_put_contents( $fileName, $result)) {
    echo "File downloaded successfully";
  }
  else {
    echo "File downloading failed.";
  }

?>
```

Either I'm missing something or I need to use a different method of getting that data. Any help or direction would be very much appreciated.